# How to use tune parameters for multilabel classification in mlr?

Tags: multilabel-classification, hyperparameters, mlr

## problem

I am trying to run a multilabel classification in r using mlr package. I used https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mlr/versions/2.19.0/topics/makeMultilabelClassifierChainsWrapper to implement multilabel classification.
But I need to add hyperparameter tuning. And that seem to create all kinds of problems. I followed the example on https://mlr.mlr-org.com/articles/tutorial/tune.html for tuning parameters.
tuneParams requires the argument resample and there I get stuck.

## example data

```
age <- c(round(rnorm(120,mean = 50,sd = 10)))
sex <- c(round(rnorm(120,mean = 0.5,sd = 0.2)))
l1 <- as.logical(c(round(rnorm(120,mean = 0.5,sd = 0.2))))
l2 <- as.logical(c(round(rnorm(120,mean = 0.5,sd = 0.2))))
l3 <- as.logical(c(round(rnorm(120,mean = 0.5,sd = 0.2))))
l4 <- as.logical(c(round(rnorm(120,mean = 0.5,sd = 0.2))))
data <- as.data.frame(cbind(age,sex,l1,l2,l3,l4))
```

In reality I have 12 labels, but I left the others out to make it easier to look at.
The idea is that l1 untill l4 are logical vectors. Somehow that doesn't work, so I hope you can fix that. But be aware that that is not my main question.

## code

```
task <- makeMultilabelTask(data = data, target = label_bact) 

ps <- makeParamSet(
    makeDiscreteParam("ntree",values = c(50,100,150,200,300,500,550)),
    makeDiscreteParam("mtry",values = c(1,2,3,4,5))
)
ctrl <- makeTuneControlGrid()
rdesc <- makeResampleDesc(method = "CV",iters = 5, predict = "test",
                          stratify.cols = c(l1,l2,l3,l4)
measure  <- acc
learner <- "classif.randomForest"
lrn <- makeLearner(learner)
lrn <- makeMultilabelClassifierChainsWrapper(lrn, order = NULL) 
lrn <- setPredictType(lrn,"prob")
res <- tuneParams(lrn,task = task,resample = rdesc, par.set = ps,control = ctrl)
```

## error

The error that I get:

```
Error in tuneParams(lrn, task = task, resample = rdesc, par.set = ps,  : 
  Assertion on 'resample.fun' failed: Must be a function, not 'CVDesc/ResampleDesc'.
```

So I added the code line:

```
r <- resample(learner = lrn,task = task,rdesc)
```

and this tells me that

```
Error in makeResampleInstance(resampling, task = task) : 
  Stratification for tasks of type 'multilabel' not supported
```

## check

This is confirmed by:

```
>rdesc
Resample description: cross-validation with 5 iterations.
Predict: test
Stratification: FALSE
```

## questions

- So first question is how can I solve the stratification (in the makeResampleDesc function) for multiple outcome labels?
- Second question is how can I make the tuneParams function work?
- Related question is is there a way to skip the resample argument as I already do CV and stratification outside these functions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1. Please do not post multiple questions at once. 2. The stratification error seems pretty descriptive. 3. You always need a resampling method when tuning params (not sure why you are doing something "outside" or what you mean by this). 4. Try to include a full reproducible example in one code block which **minimal**. This Q (and your former one) are too big and scattered to give decent answers.

Comment: @pat-s 2. Do you have an idea how to solve that? 3. I use nested CV and pass the inner train data to the function that handles multilabel classification. 4. What is wrong with the current code block?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
rf <- makeLearner("classif.randomForest", predict.type = "response", par.vals = list(ntree = 200, mtry = 3))
     
rf$par.vals <- list(importance = TRUE)
     
rf=makeDownsampleWrapper(rf, dw.stratify = TRUE)

rf=makeMultilabelClassifierChainsWrapper( rf ) 

rf_param <- makeParamSet(
makeIntegerParam("ntree",lower = 50, upper = 500),
makeIntegerParam("mtry", lower = 3, upper = 10),
makeIntegerParam("nodesize", lower = 10, upper = 50)
)

rancontrol <- makeTuneControlRandom(maxit = 5L)

#set 3 fold cross validation
 set_cv <- makeResampleDesc("CV",iters = 3L)

#hypertuning
 rf_tune <- tuneParams(learner = rf, resampling = set_cv,  task =base_pred.task, par.set = rf_param, control = rancontrol, measures = multilabel.hamloss)
```

It works for me! I hope it`ll work for you